# AreaChart, LineChart, ColumnChart, BarChart WinRT XAML Toolkit Error

Tags: xaml, charts, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Hello I try to implement Charting with WinRT XAML Toolkit for windows phone 8.1.
It runs well while I do debug, but the page which contains chart can not be navigated after I release it.

But it only happened when I add Area,Line,Column, and Bar Chart, it works fine with pie.

Please let me know if something I need to do to fix this,
I install the Toolkit using Nuget Package Manager.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a repro project you could share?

Comment: Off course, where should I share it?

Comment: Wherever is fine. Dropbox or onedrive?

Comment: Onedrive is okay, can I get your Onedrive id?

Comment: No, just share a file from yours.

Comment: That's not a repro project - it's you full app! :)
Try to create a small project where you try to do the same thing you have a problem with here. Often while creating a minimum repro project you learn the fix to your problem and if not - you'll have something to share to ask your question.

Comment: Ah I see, my apologize.
I think repro is a copy from my app.
I create this one : http://1drv.ms/1yr15Qp
thank you

Comment: @FilipSkakun

Sir I still can't figure out why the page can not be navigated, pls let me know if I can fix this, thank you